# PHP hosted on IIS gives 500 on every alternate call

Tags: php, windows, apache, batch-file, iis

I have a PHP Script in which it executes a batch(.bat) file using passthru() function. The output of batch file is printed via using echo statement.

This PHP Script works absolutely fine when hosted on Apache webserver, however the same PHP script produces 500.0 error on every alternate call, when hosted on IIS 7.5

I did some research and found out that if PHP script takes long time to execute, the browser gets unresponsive.

Hence, I edited the PHP script to write into a file like "Before executing batch file" and "After executing batch file".

As there 500.0 error was displayed, the file was still getting updated by above lines. This concludes that while the script is getting executed but browser is displaying 500.0

Is there any settings that can be tweaked in IIS?
This problem occurs only for IIS 7.5. When I use Apache it works like a charm.

Comment: Are you loking to the error.log file to detect problem? may be this will help you http://support.microsoft.com/kb/942031/en

Comment: No file is getting generated under FailedReqLogFiles folder.
The only log file which gets update is u_ex<today`s date>.log.
Is that what you are asking for? I don`t have much knowledge of IIS.

Comment: The error code which I get is 0x800700e9. The error description is "The page cannot be displayed because an internal server error has occurred."
Module is FastCgiModule.

Comment: Open your PHP.ini and look for the "error_log" value. Make sure it points to a file where the IIS worker process can write. Also check the "error_reporting" value and make sure it includes "E_ALL".
After that, open the file pointed at by the "error_log" value: it should contain more information about what broke.

Comment: I have verified logs are not updated for a 500.0 failure request. Although, for other type failures I can see the update.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've had the exact same problem as you; executing a batch file via exec(), shell_exec(), etc, would result in an internal 500 server error every other time I refreshed the page.

I resolved this by removing all PAUSE commands from the batch file.

Make sure you don't have any breaks in the flow of the batch file. That is, if user input is required at any point during the execution of the batch script php will hang and the server will time out.

Hope this helps!

(I'd comment but I don't have 50 reputation)

Comment: Wow!!! It would have been great, if I would have got this answer before. It WORKED... However, I created a servlet, since batch files were executing java class.
But you did solved my problem.

Comment: Thank you Simeon. It's 2022 and the error occurred because of the exec...
Changed it to the "pclose(popen('start test.py,'r'));" method instead that doesn't block the thread.